# Can't properly forward GoDaddy domain to Heroku server via HTTPS

Tags: http, heroku, https, dns, hosting

I have a problem with configuring Godaddy DNS and Heroku hosting server.

**The goal is**: when I type `www.example.com` or `example.com` as URL, it needs to go `https://www.example.com`.

Right now when I go `www.example.com` or `example.com,` it goes `http://www.example.com`

**Configurations are:**

On Heroku

- `heroku domains:add www.example.com` (SSL is working. Cert issued)

On GoDaddy

- DNS record: `type=CNAME name=www value=www.example.com.herokudns.com`
- DNS forwarding domain: `forwardto=https://www.example.com forwardtype=Permanent(301) settings=Forwardonly`
- DNS forwarding subdomain: `subdomain=example.com forwardto=https://www.example.com forwardtype=Permanent(301) settings=Forwardonly`

P.S. If I manually go `https://www.example.com` the browser shows that it is secured

**Edit:** *Update my nameservers and DNS settings to support this change* is checked

Answer (score 1):

Under GoDaddy doamin forwarding, make sure to check the box next to "Update my nameservers and DNS settings to support this change", then save.

If that is done. Confirm that your local dns cache has updated. Run these two commands, if the IP addresses returned are different, you may need to clear your cache or make sure that you haven't made manual changes to your host file.

nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8
ping example.com

Comment: Thank you for the response Jordan. I forgot to mention that the "update my nameservers and DNS settings to support this change" is checked. Even with that it didn't work. But you gave interesting idea to confirm that local dns cache has updated which is little bit unclear for me. How do I confirm that my local dns cache has updated? Is it related to browser or the server? (I use Windows 10 x64, my project that deployed on heroku uses Node.js) I have limited knowledge about servers. So please, explain me as you would explain to a beginner

Comment: @MardONE Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache?  If so, the `.htaccess` file is the best way to [change the default domain](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file).

Comment: I use Node.js as a server. Is there any work around for that?

Comment: @MardONE Not that I know of, sorry.  I don't mess with Node usually.  However, can I see the main JS file for it?  Usually there is some line where you start a server and listen on an IP (like `localhost`).